# Why do kube-dns SRV entries have 0 for the port number of a service in a GKE cluster?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kube-dns, gke-networking

I have a free trial cluster in GKE. In this cluster I have a deployment and a service. When I do `nslookup -type=srv <service_name>` inside a helper pod with DNS utils, I get entries containing `0` instead of the actual port (eg 17000) number of the service. This problem prevents me from moving on. I will be glad for your help.

```
C:\>kubectl exec dnsutils -- nslookup -type=srv my-svc
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.
Server:         10.120.0.10
Address:        10.120.0.10#53

my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local   service = 10 14 0 3133626239396130.my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local.
my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local   service = 10 14 0 6333336363666162.my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local.
my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local   service = 10 14 0 3132373039303465.my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local.
my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local   service = 10 14 0 3838326161363637.my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local.
my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local   service = 10 14 0 3135393163303035.my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local.
my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local   service = 10 14 0 3463343863303565.my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local.
my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local   service = 10 14 0 3436353934633363.my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local.
```

Comment: The command that you are running will only indicate that an SRV record exists but will not actually tell you the port.  To get the port, you need to explicitly look it up using the _portname._protocol format.  For example, if "my-svc" has a port named "grpc" in the "my-ns" namespace, you would run `kubectl exec dnsutils -- nslookup -type=srv _grpc._tcp.my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local` to get the port for the grpc service.

See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/16284 as well for an explanation at to why this is the case.

Comment: @GariSingh, my service is using a custom tcp port (eg 17000).

Comment: In your Service definition, you can name the port and replace `my-port-name` with that name using the `_my-port-name._tcp.my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local`  syntax.

Comment: @GariSingh, thank you very much. Your last comment was very helpful. My mistake was that I didn't read the documentation for Kubernetes services accurately and skipped the section on named ports because of that. Once the port was given a name, everything worked. The `nslookup -type=srv _my-port-name._tcp.my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local` returns port number.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The first command that was ran will only indicate that an SRV record exists but will not actually tell us the port. To get the port, we need to explicitly look it up using the _portname._protocol format. I.e. if "my-svc" has a port named "grpc" in the "my-ns" namespace, you would run kubectl exec dnsutils -- nslookup -type=srv _grpc._tcp.my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local to get the port for the grpc service. See [DNS SRV port lookup fails](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/16284)  as well for an explanation as to why this is the case.

In the Service definition, the port can be named and we can replace my-port-name with that name using the _my-port-name._tcp.my-svc.my-ns.svc.cluster.local syntax" - @Gari Singh.